# Python logging not outputing debug messages

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to use python logging module to output messages to a file, I found some configurations online and customized it to what I need but it isn't printing what I want it to print. No DEBUG level messages are appearing in the file handler with DEBUG level.

I am using this JSON configuration for the logger:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "formatters": {
    "simple": {
      "format": "%(asctime)s : %(levelname)-8s - %(name)s : %(message)s",
      "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    }
  },
  "handlers": {
    "file_handler": {
      "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
      "level": "DEBUG",
      "formatter": "simple",
      "filename": "info.log",
      "maxBytes": 1E6,
      "backupCount": 5,
      "encoding": "utf8"
    },
    "error_file_handler": {
      "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
      "level": "ERROR",
      "formatter": "simple",
      "filename": "errors.log",
      "maxBytes": 1E6,
      "backupCount": 5,
      "encoding": "utf8"
    }
  },
  "root": {
    "level": "INFO", # EDIT - change this to DEBUG to fix
    "handlers": ["file_handler", "error_file_handler"]
  }
}
```

And I execute this code:

```
import logging
import logging.config as lconfig

import json

with open('logger.json', 'rt') as f:
    config = json.load(f)
lconfig.dictConfig(config)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info('info')
logger.warning('warning')
logger.debug('debug')
logger.error('error')
logger.critical('critical')
```

The problem here is the file `info.log` does not have the debug line, the output is this:

```
2020-01-03 15:32:23 : INFO     - __main__ : info
2020-01-03 15:32:23 : WARNING  - __main__ : warning
2020-01-03 15:32:23 : ERROR    - __main__ : error
2020-01-03 15:32:23 : CRITICAL - __main__ : critical
```

What should I do to fix this and print debug messages to the `info.log` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the level on the root logger to DEBUG rather than INFO.

```
"root": { 
  "level": "DEBUG",
```

Comment: How to do this? Where should I add this configuration?